# Labelling X and Y axis in Dymola plot

Tags: plot, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I have drawn a plot using "plotArrays" function in Dymola. I would like to label X-axis in meters(Ideally, I need it to be flexible so that I can later change it to millimeters, micrometers, etc..). I want to label Y-axis similarly in volts which I have done already using

```
plotArrays(x_axis,phie,legend=names,units=fill("V",size(phie,2)));
```

and I can read the values in volts and also change to mV etc.. However, its not 'visible' in Y-axis as you can see in the plot below. So, How can I label the axes separately?
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any more efficient possibility than this:

```
createPlot(id=1, erase=false, grid=true, leftTitleType=2, leftTitle="myLabelY", bottomTitleType=2, bottomTitle="myLabelX")
```

with:

- `id` being the number shown in the original plot
- `erase=false` to ensure that the content is not modified
- `grid=true` (re-)enabling the grid
- `*TitleType=2` saying that there is a custom title
- `*Title` being the string to put there

This will result in the plot being resized to the default size. You can use `plotSetup()` to get the current setup, including `position`, which you can then pass (manually) to the `createPlot()` command to result in the original size again.

Not very elegant, but I don't know any other possibility...